# GitLab-CI: Use a job-variable in release section

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In my CI-Pipeline of Gitlab I try to set a tag-name for a [release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release).

The tag-name should be set by a Job-Variable, but it will always use the "default" value. But it should use the "overwritten" variable value from by script section.

In the GitLab-CI.yml I set the default value of the var `VERSION_TAG` to `v0.0.0`, in the script section the value is overwritten with `v1.2.3`. In the echo command the right version-tag is printed correct. In the release section the variable is then again the default value `v0.0.0`, so the tag of the release will be wrong. The v1.2.3 will be set by a script and not hard-coded in future.

Here my GitLab-CI.yml, important is the job `add_version_tag` (I removed some rules, to improve the readability)

```yaml
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

stages:
  - build
  - release

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'

variables:
  DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: "true"
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: "true"

building:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Start Pseudo Build Job ..."
    # - dotnet build

add_version_tag:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  variables:
    VERSION_TAG: "v0.0.0"
  script:
    - VERSION_TAG=v1.2.3
    - echo "Create tag $VERSION_TAG"
  release:
    tag_name: $VERSION_TAG
    tag_message: "Release $VERSION_TAG"
    name: "Release $VERSION_TAG of $CI_PROJECT_NAME"
    description: "Release $VERSION_TAG at $CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT based on $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```

The output from the logs of the ci-pipeline

```
...
$ echo "Create tag $VERSION_TAG"
Create tag v1.2.3
...
$ release-cli create --name "Release v0.0.0 of version-handling" --description "Release v0.0.0 at 2024-01-29T11:44:34Z based on xxxxxxxx" --tag-name "v0.0.0" --tag-message "Release v0.0.0"
...
```

How can I use a "job-variable" in a release job section?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html) variables are not passed from `script` or `before_script` to `release`.

The solution documented [below](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html#create-release-metadata-in-a-custom-script) states to create a `variables.env` file as an artifact and pass that to the next job doin the release.

Comment: Also watch out for the caveat that creating a release may create a tag that will trigger the build again (also in the docs)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks [@mpolitze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067865/mpolitze) for the hint out of the [ducumentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/release_cicd_examples.html)

> Environment variables set in `before_script` or `script` are not available for expanding in the same job. Read more about potentially making variables available for expanding.

I was not aware of that before. By reading the workaround with the .env file, I came up with the solution below.

I was able to solve the "hand over of variables" by using a file `VERSION_TAG_FILE`, and still stay a inside a single job. Staying in one single job, without artifacts, was one of my goals.

I use `echo to file` and `cat` to read from the file

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

stages:
  - build
  - release

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'

variables:
  DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT: "true"
  DOTNET_NOLOGO: "true"

building:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Start Pseudo Build Job ..."
    # - dotnet build

add_version_tag:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  variables:
    VERSION_TAG: "v0.0.0"
+   VERSION_TAG_FILE: "version.txt"
  script:
    - VERSION_TAG=v1.2.3
    - echo "Create tag $VERSION_TAG"
+   - echo $VERSION_TAG > $VERSION_TAG_FILE
  release:
+    tag_name: $(cat $VERSION_TAG_FILE)
+    tag_message: "Release $(cat $VERSION_TAG_FILE)"
+    name: "Release $(cat $VERSION_TAG_FILE) of $CI_PROJECT_NAME"
+    description: "Release $(cat $VERSION_TAG_FILE) at $CI_PIPELINE_CREATED_AT based on $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
```